# Anyone recommend TFS tools for keeping requirements docs updated?

Tags: tfs, requirements

I've got a problem at work where devs and QA are routinely using out-dated requirements documents.  Were using TFS.

Is there some kind of tool that exists where when a requirements document is updated, that update gets pushed to every dev using it? Ideally some kind of pop-up that notifies them that there's a newer version, and they can click yes to download, etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS then updating the local copy to the current version on a regular basis will be enough for the person to get the latest version.  I am not sure about generating notifications though, I would think that doing that would be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Most teams (agile teams at least) have moved away from "managing by documents" to "managing by lists".  What this means is that you track and manage a list of requirements rather than a document.  You may still have some documents, but they are a point in time document, not a living document that is constantly updated.

Instead keep a list of User Stories/PBI's/Requirements, and include relevant data on each item in the list.  This allows you to move each item through a set of states, and report against that metadata to track progress.  If you use TFS Work Items to manage this data anybody can easily setup notifications when WI's they are interested in change.